# How to implement and publish virtual audio driver to Apple App Store?

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, driverkit, macos-system-extension

At 3:38-4:00 in the session video, it seems Baek San Chang says that AudioDriverKit will not be allowed to be used for virtual audio devices

Video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10190/

Here is what he says:

> Keep in mind that the sample code presented is purely for
> demonstrative purposes and creates a virtual audio driver that is not
> associated with a hardware device, and so entitlements will not be
> granted for that kind of use case.
>
> For virtual audio driver, where device is all that is needed, the
> audio server plugin driver model should continue to be used.

The mentioning of sample code is a little confusing; Does he mean the entitlements for hardware access won't be granted for a virtual device? That would seem obvious.

But if he means the entitlements for driver kit extensions (com.apple.developer.driverkit and com.apple.developer.driverkit.allow-any-userclient-access) won't be granted for virtual audio devices, and this is why AudioServerPlugins should still be used, then that's another story.

Are we allowed to use AudioDriverKit Extension for Virtual Devices?

The benefit of having the extension bundled with the app rather than requiring an installer is a significant reason to use an extension if allowed.

I need to create a virtual audio driver that presents a virtual microphone and a virtual speaker to the user. The user can then select these virtual endpoints in 3rd party audio communication apps like Skype, Zoom etc. The virtual audio driver implementation then routes audio between physical devices (selected by the user in the virtual driver userspace control app) and the virtual devices.

It is a requirement that the virtual audio driver and its control app can be published to the Apple app store for users to download and install on their machine without any problems.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Hi, do you have any update on that?

Answer (score 3):

> How should I go about this?

Apply for the entitlements straight away (don't lie on your request form obviously), wait until AudioDriverKit is out of beta, then file a Developer Tech Support TSI and explain what you're trying to do and ask what the policy is. I haven't seen any written policy on this, and the information in the video may or may not be accurate.

Don't forget that you don't just need the entitlements; your virtual audio drivers will also need to pass App Store review, so I'd make sure to get something in writing before you spend all that effort implementing your driver.

<s>One more comment: `com.apple.developer.driverkit.allow-any-userclient-access` is not generally needed, and whether or not you need to apply for it depends on the architecture you are planning for your driver.</s> **Update:** I'm not sure what I was thinking of when I wrote this last bit 2 years ago. As far as I'm aware, you do need this entitlement for deploying AudioDriverKit on macOS.

Comment: On the associated [code project from WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiodriverkit/creating_an_audio_device_driver#:~:text=a%20sine%20tone.-,Note,-When%20creating%20a). It is mentioned again that AudioDriverKit only supports physical audio devices.

Comment: Do you know when`com.apple.developer.driverkit.allow-any-userclient-access` is needed and for which architectures?

Comment: @tuple_cat I'm now not sure what I was thinking of specifically when I wrote that comment to be honest. I think you probably *do* need it when targeting AudioDriverKit on macOS; you don't necessarily need it if you're building a dext that will be paired with an audio server plugin, but for a virtual device, you wouldn't need the dext, only the ASP.